# When you're mentioned in a chat room, it should ping the tab

Tags: feature-request, chat

Steps to recreate:

1. Enter 2 chat rooms.
2. Leave one of them.
3. Have someone @you in the room you left in step 2.
4. A banner appears indicating that you've been mentioned in the room you left in step 2.

Desired result:
Beyond the banner, it would be nice if that also pinged that tab so that you know something's up in chat.

- I'm referring to the thing that open tabs do when they have their color change in Firefox here as 'pinging.'  An example is when you have `/questions` open in a background tab and someone edits a question or answer, posts a new question, or posts a new answer.  I.e. the highlighting that you see on the right tab here:

[image: Image of tabs, with one highlighted.]

Comment: I'm still unclear what you mean -- are you talking about the `(*)` that appears in the tab title?

Comment: @balpha Yes, that's part of it.  I'll add a pic.

Comment: We don't do that highlighting, at least not directly. Maybe FF does that when the title changes?

Comment: @balpha *Something* the site does triggers said highlighting.  It doesn't do *that thing* when you're mentioned in a room you're not currently in.